# How to write piecewise function in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have tried to train only one Tensorflow variable `theta` by using `tf.select` as the code shown below.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy.random import RandomState
from tensorflow.contrib.losses import mean_squared_error

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

random_state = RandomState()


def generate_data(n_train, n_test, theta=0.2):
    X_train = random_state.uniform(size=[n_train])
    X_test = random_state.uniform(size=[n_test])
    y_train = np.where((X_train > theta), np.sin(X_train), np.cos(X_train))
    y_test = np.where((X_test > theta), np.sin(X_test), np.cos(X_test))
    return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)


(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = generate_data(1000, 300)

intN = np.int64
floatN = np.float32
intT = tf.int64
floatT = tf.float32

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=floatT, name=r'x', shape=[None])
y_true = tf.placeholder(dtype=floatT, name=r'y_true', shape=[None])
theta = tf.get_variable(dtype=floatT, name=r'theta', initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(shape=[], dtype=floatT))

y_pred = tf.select(
    tf.greater(x, theta),
    tf.sin(x),
    tf.cos(x), name=r'y_pred')

loss = mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_true)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as session:
    all_variables = tf.global_variables() + tf.local_variables()
    all_variables_initializer = tf.variables_initializer(all_variables)
    session.run(all_variables_initializer)

    _, batch_loss = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={
        x: X_train,
        y_true: y_train,
    })

    tf.logging.info(r'batch loss {:.4f}'.format(batch_loss))
```

But I got

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ['Tensor("theta/read:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)'] and loss Tensor("mean_squared_error/value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).

So how to do this? If I really want use `tf.cond` or `tf.where` or `tf.select` or `tf.case` instead of something like `sigmoid`, I mean how to do condition braches (piecewise function) in Tensorflow in general?

Comment: I don't think you can do the chain rule conditionally

Comment: You want to optimize for `theta` right? This is not going to work since `tf.greater(x, y)` is not differentiable w.r.t. `y`. Backprop through `tf.cond` etc. works as long as the graph is differentiable.